# Pandas DataFrame select the specific columns with NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a two-column DataFrame, I want to select the rows with `NaN` in either column.

I used this method `df[ (df['a'] == np.NaN) | (df['b'] == np.NaN) ]`
However it returns an empty answer. I don't know what's the problem

Comment: shouldn't the title be changed here? 'rows' where it says 'columns'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) for finding `NaN` values:

```
df[ (df['a'].isnull()) | (df['b'].isnull()) ]
```

[Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing).

Answer (score 1):

You could apply `isnull()` to the whole dataframe then check if the rows have any nulls with `any(1)`

```
df[df.isnull().any(1)]
```

---

#### Timing

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice((np.nan, 1), (1000000, 2), p=(.2, .8)), columns=['A', 'B'])
```

[image]

I did not expect these results...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **isna()** method with axis **1** (i.e., along the columns):

```
df[df.isna().any(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **isna()** as well:

```
df[df['merged_key_words'].isna() | df['key_words'].isna()]
```